# Import files into a collection from CLI (django command)

Tags: django, wagtail

I'm trying to build a django command to upload files and create associated pages for them.

My docs are PDF files, and my problem is to automatically "upload" those files into the right target "media" directory, without explicit copying them with my command script from the 'docs repository' to the `MEDIA_ROOT` defined directory.

I've tryed to use:

**Code**

```
f = File(open(file_path, 'r'))
# models.OfficeDocument is an inheritor of BaseDocument class
new_document, created = models.OfficeDocument.objects.get_or_create(title=title,
                                                                        collection=collection,
                                                                        file=f)
```

**Error**

```
SuspiciousFileOperation: The joined path (<my_local_path>) is located outside of the base path component (<MEDIA_ROOT path>)
```

but wagtail says me I'm not in the right directory (not in `MEDIA_ROOT`)

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to save the documents with their files in the current location, without copying them to the new location first. You could add some code to copy the files to the right location, or it seems reasonable to mimic what the [Wagtail documents add view](https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/blob/master/wagtail/wagtaildocs/views/documents.py#L92) does here—instantiate a modelform, clean it, and call its save method. That will handle the saving of the document as it has the `upload_to` property configured on the file field.

Try:

```
from wagtail.wagtailcore.models import get_root_collection_id

collection = get_root_collecion_id()
user = some_user_you_will_attribute_these_to
doc = Document(uploaded_by_user=user)
upload_dict = {
    'title': some_title,
    'file': f,
    'collection': collection,
    'tags': '',
}
form = DocumentForm(upload_dict, f, instance=doc, user=request.user)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
```

You might find that the file object needs to be something like a wrapped Django UploadedFile instance instead, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/files/uploads/

Comment: I've used another method : I use the storage abstraction through the "get_default_storage", which gives me an abstraction to the storage.